# Mix-up Testing in agile development

Tags: terminology, functional, integration-testing

Cross-module testing is a specific term that is only used internally in some organizations. To be more clear, it is also call mix-up testing, a cross testing activity between scrum teams.

I am intending to research this testing approach so that I can implement it in my company.

1. Is it similar to cross-functional testing?
2. What are differences between mix-up testing and integration testing?
3. What is the best way to practice mix-up testing in an agile development?
4. Any example of organization or company practices for cross module testing.

Also, you can share you experience about mix-up testing.

Or can you suggest any materials related to this topic.

Comment: Does your application have modules? In your organization is it each team testing scenarios only specific for its module? Are they some user scenarios to go across multiple modules? E.g. creating a user in authentication module and assigning privileges in authorization module. How are you testing such scenarios?

Comment: Also why are you supposed to research on this? Each time a company invests into researching something it's because it's trying to solve a problem. What problem is it trying to solve?

Comment: As we have different scrum teams, we are focusing develops feature in different area of a product. For example, team A is focusing on the General system, team B is focusing on Customer related feature and team C is focusing on Documents related feature. Each scrum team have different target. We want to enhance the way testing activity work to be better and find as many bug as possible. @dzieciou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider it to be integrated testing.

You have different areas of functionality in the organization.  The different areas have team of people supporting them.  Each team will test their part of the product or system and then rely on other teams to do their part.
The problem is that there are interactions between them and that *these* interactions should be tested.

For example, in a medical setting you may have teams for registration, labs, pharmacy, xray, inpatient etc, but who tests that when a patient is registered with 'x' characteristics you can then perform y lab tests and z x-rays.  Or in a SAS (Software as a Service) company, how to ensure that new customers of various characteristics can register, can buy various products, and can do it through devices and browsers of various types.

Answer (score 0):

What we simply did in such a case was we sat with testers from different teams and defined scenarios crossing different features and modules.